# Responsive footer goes to top on mobile; sticks to bottom on phone emulators and desktop?

Tags: html, css, mobile, responsive-design, footer

Recently deployed a responsive word press template with minimal plugins.
Footer works on mobile phone emulators and desktop. On actual devices, it shoots to right below the headers above content. I want the footer to stick to the bottom.

My mobiel test device is a nexus 5(1080p).

I've tried altering the footer with the usual suggestions but nothing works for both. I even turned off the php functions fo determining mobile but it still doesn't work.

Here's the footer CSS

Here is the responsive CSS and php code

```
    if ($px_theme_option['responsive'] == "on") {
                    echo '<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0">';
                    wp_enqueue_style('responsive_css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/responsive.css');
```

CSS( relvant footer classes from responsive.css)

```
/*============      Media 768Px Start   ============ */
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 979px) {


    #footer{
            overflow:hidden;
        }

/*============      Media 420Px Start   ============ */
@media (max-width: 767px) {
    #footer{
        height:67px;
}
    #footer p{
        margin:0 0 0 10px;
    }
    #footer{
        overflow:hidden;
    }


/*============      Media 300Px Start   ============ */
@media (max-width: 480px) {

#footer{
        height:120px;
    }
    #footer p{
        margin:0;
        padding:0px 44px 0px 0px;
    }
```

Might be relevant, the news articles are right on top, and it's covering them. I assume this shoots it below and it's not applying(becuase I switched some catogories around in world press and pages?).

```
.news-section article figure{
    height:100%;
    }
    #footer p{
    margin:0 0 0 10px;
}


    #footer{
        overflow:hidden;
    }
/*============     Media 940Px Start    ============ */
@media screen and (min-width: 900px) and (max-width: 1054px){

    #footer{
        overflow:hidden;
    }
```

Default(I assume desktop since it's in seperate style.css file)

```
  #footer {
        max-width: 1160px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        background: #141414;
        position: relative;
        z-index: 99;
        height: 56px;
        font-size: 0;
        line-height: 0;
        padding-top: 17px;
        border-top: 10px solid #0c0c0c;
        box-shadow: -10px 10px #141414,10px 10px #141414 ;
    }
    #footer p {
        float: left;
        line-height: 25px;
        margin: 0 0 0 35px;
        font-size: 11px;
        color: #555;
        font-style: normal;
    }
```

Footer HTML

```
      </div>
            </div> 
        </div>
        <!-- Inner Main -->
    </div>
    <footer id="footer">
        <p class="coptyright">
            <?php echo do_shortcode(htmlspecialchars_decode($px_theme_option['copyright'])); ?>  
            <?php echo do_shortcode(htmlspecialchars_decode($px_theme_option['powered_by'])); ?>
        </p>
        <?php
            if($px_theme_option['footer_social_icons'] == 'on'){
                px_social_network();
            }
        ?>
        <a href="" class="btn btngotop"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-o-up"></i></a>
    </footer>
</div>
<!-- Wrapper End -->
<?php 
px_footer_settings();
wp_footer();?>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding

```
clear:both
```

This should keep it at the bottom.

Comment: Didn't work, I added the responsive.css which has more concerning mobile size. Odd how it works for those only if on a emulator.

Comment: Added it to responsive.css as opposed to default desktop .CSS...it worked! Thanks!